# When extending Euclid's lemma to an arbitrary product, why must 2 be in the induction base case?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, induction

The statement I'm trying to prove:

Let $p$ be prime, $n \in N$, and $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \in Z$. If $p \mid (\prod^n_{i=1}a_i)$ then $p \mid a_i$ for some $i$.

So if $p$ divides a product of integers, it must divide one of the integers in the product.

*Proof.* I prove by induction.

**Base Case** The base case is given - when $n=1$, $p \mid a_1 \implies p \mid a_1$, trivially.

**Induction Step** Suppose the theorem holds for $n=m$. Suppose $p \mid (\prod^{m+1}_{i=1}a_i)$. Then

$$
p \mid (\prod^{m}_{i=1}a_i) \cdot a_{m+1}
$$

By Euclid's lemma $p \mid (\prod^{m}_{i=1}a_i)$ or $p \mid a_{m+1}$. In the first case, $p \mid a_i$ for some $i$ by hypothesis. In the second, $p \mid a_i$ for $i = m+1$. So in either case $p \mid a_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq m+1$. So if the lemma holds for $n=m$ it holds for $n=m+1$ and thus holds for all $k \in N$. QED

Standard proof of this statement. Here's what I don't understand - every other proof shows $n=2$ in the base case. Why? Can't we show 2 in the inductive step?

Comment: If you take $n=2$ as the base case, you use the base case, not Euclid's lemma, when you split the product of $m+1$ terms into a product of two integers.  This makes the 2-way split a lemma to use in the inductive step and puts that lemma in the base case.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I'm not following. Are you saying that, in my inductive step, when I split the product into two integers, I'll no longer rely on Euclid's lemma to show p divides one of the integers?

Comment: Correct.  Given the $n=2$ base case, that "$p$ divides the product of the two integers $\prod_{i=1}^m a_i$ and $a_{m+1}$, so divides one of them" is the base case, so is immediate.

Answer (score 1):

When you say $p \mid (\prod_{i=1}^m a_i)$ or  $p\mid a_{m+1}$, my question is: how do you know?

It would be nice to have proven if $p\mid a_1a_2$ then $p\mid a_1$ or $p\mid a_2$. I.e. you actually *need* the base case of $n=2$ to be true as you use both this fact and the inductive hypothesis in the inductive step.

Comment: We know by Euclid's lemma, yes? At which point in the inductive step do I need to rely on proving n=2 in the base case? Thanks for the response, by the way.

Comment: Then Euclid lemma *is* the base case .

Comment: So by including 2 in the base case, we no longer rely on Euclid's lemma and the proof is self-contained and thus "more correct" or at least better in some way? Is my proof "correct" but inferior?

Comment: Since Euclids Lemma assumes a prime dividing a product of integers, and we are trying to extend Euclids lemma, your base case of a prime dividing a singular integer really has nothing to do with Euclid’s lemma.

Comment: No. The proof for the base case is the proof of Euclids lemma, so you definitely need Euclids lemma. If you perhaps have not proven Euclids lemma yet, in order to prove its extension to an arbitrary product of integers you would first need to prove that it’s true for a product of just two integers.

Answer (score 1):

Call the statement $P_n$. The standard proof uses $\rm\color{#c00}{strong}$ induction with base case $\,n=2\,$ and it uses the strong inductive step $\,\color{#c00}{P_2}\ \&\ P_n\Rightarrow P_{n+1}$.

Your proof effectively transforms the strong induction into a normal induction by moving the proof of $P_2$ into a Lemma (call it $\rm\color{#0a0}{EL}$ = Euclid's Lemma). So  your transformed proof has base case $\,n=1\,$ and the normal inductive step $\, P_n\Rightarrow P_{n+1}$ by $\rm\color{#0a0}{EL}$.

Obviously the same method works to transform into a normal induction any complete induction that uses a fixed number of $\rm\color{#c00}{initial\  cases}$ in its strong induction step.

**Remark** $ $ The proof is a special case of the inductive $n$-ary extension of a hom, i.e.

$$f(a_2 * a_1) = f(a_2)\sqcup f(a_1)\ \Rightarrow\ f(a_n* \cdots* a_1) = f(a_n)\sqcup \cdots \sqcup f(a_1)\qquad$$

OP is case $\,f(n) = [\![\:\! p\mid n\:\!]\!]\,$ where the brackets denote boolean truth value, and where $\sqcup $ is $\vee$, i.e. logical or. Above, for simplicity of notation, I assume the operations are associative (else e.g. right-associate everything).